# Loop until I get correct user

Tags: ruby, redis

I have users stored in Redis and want to be able to call only certain subsets from a set, if I don't get the correct user back I want to put it back in the set and then try again until I get one of the desired users

```
@redis = Redis.new
@randUser = @redis.spop("users")

if @randUser.include?(["user_4", "user_5", "user_6"])
  @redis.sadd("users", @randUser)
  # Run @randUser = @redis.spop("users") again
else
  $user_username = @redis.hget(@randUser, "username")
  $user_password = @redis.hget(@randUser, "password")
end
```

I can't quite get the logic right in my head, how else could I approach this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `if` to `while`:

```
while ["user_4", "user_5"].include?(@randUser = @redis.spop("users")) do
  @redis.sadd("users", @randUser)
end

$user_username = @redis.hget(@randUser, "username")
$user_password = @redis.hget(@randUser, "password")
```

Please note, that you actually mixed up receiver and parameters on `Array#include?`

Comment: Ah thank you, yes I got things the wrong way around which is why I probably got confused.. Thank you for clearing that up for me